# how to say "Sahur" in English?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

muslim have an early meal before they fast, and they eat the meal around 3 to 5 AM or before sunrise. do you know specific word of this "early meal"?

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking, "What is a single word for a pre-dawn meal that would be understood by English-speakers who are not familiar with Muslim traditions?" then I'm afraid there isn't one since fasting during daylight hours is not a common observance for non-Muslims.  The best you could do is use the phrase **pre-dawn meal**.

If you're asking, "What is the word used by English-speaking Muslims?" then the answer is, "it depends."  Generally, it's something derived from "Sahūr", but the exact spelling varies a lot between different populations with different ethnic and language backgrounds.

Wikipedia lists several [name variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suhur#Name_variations), and there "Suhoor" is listed as a UK variant.  Here in Toronto, there's a blog called "Halal Foodie" that has an annual [Toronto Ramadan Restaurant Iftar and Suhoor Guide](http://halalfoodie.ca/ramadan/ramadan-restaurant-iftar-suhoor/).  So that's two data points in favor of **Suhoor** as the Anglicized version.  But I don't have to look very hard to find Toronto-based English-language pages that use other variants like **Sahur** or **Sehri** (those seem to be used by communities with Arabic or Bengali/Urdu backgrounds, respectively).